# Restart button using html & js

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

How do you add a restart button on this game so that every time user click on the button it restart the game. Tried few ways to do it but i think i am dumb lol, just cant figure it out.
Anyone knows how to do that ?

How do you add a restart button on this game so that every time user click on the button it restart the game. Tried few ways to do it but i think i am dumb lol, just cant figure it out.
Anyone knows how to do that ?

```
html    
----------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Computer Choice: <span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Your Choice: <span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Result: <span id="result"></span></h2>

    <button id="rock">rock</button>
    <button id="paper">paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">scissors</button>
    <div class="restart">Re-Start</div>

    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
--------
js file
---------
const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice')
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('user-choice')
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')
const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let userChoice
let computerChoice
let result

possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = e.target.id
  userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
  generateComputerChoice()
  getResult()
}))

function generateComputerChoice() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1 // or you can use possibleChoices.length
  
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    computerChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 2) {
    computerChoice = 'scissors'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 3) {
    computerChoice = 'paper'
  }
  computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice
}

function getResult() {
  if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
    result = 'its a draw!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you lost!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "";
};
```

Comment: The easiest way is to simply call `window.reload()`. The "proper" way is to wrap the code you want to run again in a function and call the function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited as little as possible of your code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Computer Choice: <span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Your Choice: <span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Result: <span id="result"></span></h2>

    <button id="rock">rock</button>
    <button id="paper">paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">scissors</button>
    <div class="restart" id="reset">Re-Start</div>

    
    
    <script>
    const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice')
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('user-choice')
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')
const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let userChoice
let computerChoice
let result

possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = e.target.id
  userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
  generateComputerChoice()
  getResult()
}))

function generateComputerChoice() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1 // or you can use possibleChoices.length
  
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    computerChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 2) {
    computerChoice = 'scissors'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 3) {
    computerChoice = 'paper'
  }
  computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice
}

function getResult() {
  if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
    result = 'its a draw!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you lost!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("computer-choice").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("user-choice").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
  };
  </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

So basically, if you want to click the text "Re-Start" and having it "reset the game", you have to remove the text at three places : the computer's choice, your choice, and the result.

The function your wrote for it doesn't change any of those. Instead, it looks for a DOM element with the id "number", which doesn't seem to even exists.

The DOM elements you want to change have IDs "computer-choice", "user-choice" and "result".

Beside, you're trying to add a click event toward your reset function to an element with the id "reset". But it doesn't exists. You can change that by adding that ID to the text which you seem to be willing to use in that case :

```
<div class="restart">Re-Start</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="restart" id="reset">Re-Start</div>
```

And if you want to have a "restart button", then you may either edit the div with the text "Re-Start" to add a class which makes it more of a button visually speaking, or just use